# Degrees of freedom of a multiple comparission using estimability and lsmeans

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, degrees-of-freedom, generalized-least-squares, lsmeans

I have a doubt about the degrees of freedom of a multiple comparission test. My data have the following structure: One data for each day, for 14 days, in each year season (auttum, winter, spring and summer, 1, 2,3 and 4 in the script)in two different systems (Trat 1 and 2)

The data structure:

```
a <- rnorm(14, mean=2, sd=4)
b <- rnorm(14, mean=1, sd=8)
c <- rnorm(14, mean=0, sd=1)
d <- rnorm(14, mean=2, sd=3)
e <- rnorm(14, mean=4, sd=2)
f <- rnorm(14, mean=1, sd=3)
g <- rnorm(14, mean=2, sd=4)
h <- rnorm(14, mean=1, sd=0.5)


NEP<-c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)
uno<-rep(1,14)
dos<-rep(2,14)
tres<-rep(3,14)
cuatro<-rep(4,14)
estacion<-c(uno,dos,tres,cuatro,uno,dos,tres,cuatro)
Trat<-c(uno,uno,uno,uno,dos,dos,dos,dos)
data<-cbind(NEP, estacion, Trat)
data<-as.data.frame(data)
data$EsTrt <-factor(paste(data$estacion,data$Trat,sep='/'))
    data$estacion<-as.factor(data$estacion)
    data$Trat<-as.factor(data$Trat)
```

To analyse differences between each group, I adjuste a gls model and then use the packages “estimability” and “lsmeans”, in order to make paired contrasts

First, my model

```
m1.NEP <- gls(NEP~estacion*Trat, 
               weights=varIdent(form=~1|EsTrt),
               data=data)
summary(m1.NEP)
```

And then, the comparisson:

```
install.packages("lattice")
library(estimability)
library(lsmeans)

NEP.rg <- ref.grid(m1.NEP)
NEP.lsm <- lsmeans(NEP.rg,'estacion', 'Trat')
contrast(NEP.lsm, method='pairwise')
a<-confint(NEP.lsm)
plot(a)
```

My doubt is: Is it rigth that the df of the comparissions are the same that the ones of the model? (104 in both cases). If it is right... Why  are 8 df “lost”? (ie: 104 are the df, but my n=112) Is this because of the estimation of each mean for the 8 groups?  My intuition tells me that i should loose more df because of the inclusion of a term for heteroscedasticy in the model (`m1.NEP`), but this is not happening. What is it that I'm not taking into account?

I will apreciate some feedback,
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is really a question about `gls`. Those other packages just use the df supplied by the fitted model -- e.g., do `summary(m1.NEP)`. But yes, I think `gls` just subtracts the number of parameters in the model but not accounting for the additional parameters in the variance model. One could argue that it should. And if you like you could reduce the df used in the LS means via `update(NEP.rg, df = ...)`